# Date time error for character vector

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataframe that has a datetime column like this

```
When <- c("09/13/2016 11:29:00 AM", "09/13/2016 07:20:00 AM")
df <- data.frame(When)
df$When <- as.character(df$When)
```

I try to convert this to the format that I want

```
df$When <- format(strptime(df$When, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S"), "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

The above doesn't get converted to Date time format.

I have a function that I use to check dateformat

```
checkDate <- function(date, dateFormat){

  d <- try( as.Date( date, format = dateFormat))

  if( class( d ) == "try-error" || any(is.na( d )) ){
    stop( paste0("DATETIME: Need a valid DATETIME in format ", dateFormat) )
  } 

}

df$When <- checkDate(df$When, "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

I get an error

> Error in checkDate(df$When, "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p") : 
>         DATETIME: Need a valid DATETIME in format %d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p

I am not understanding on how I could solve this issue. Is it the character format that is causing the error? Could someone help me point in the right direction?

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `"%m/%d..."` instead of `"%d/%m..."`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using lubridate (mdy_hms) to extract timestamp and then date function to extract date

```
> When <- c("09/13/2016 11:29:00 AM", "09/13/2016 07:20:00 AM")
    > df <- data.frame(When)
    > df$When <- as.character(df$When)
    > df
                        When
    1 09/13/2016 11:29:00 AM
    2 09/13/2016 07:20:00 AM
> str(df)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ When: chr  "09/13/2016 11:29:00 AM" "09/13/2016 07:20:00 AM"
> library(lubridate)

Attaching package: ‘lubridate’

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    date

> df$When <- mdy_hms(df$When)
> df$Date=date(df$When)
> df
                 When       Date
1 2016-09-13 11:29:00 2016-09-13
2 2016-09-13 07:20:00 2016-09-13
```

Answer (score 0):

Two minor changes and I think it should work for you:

1. Add explicit return for `d` in you function
2. Change your format to start with `%m` instead of `%d`.

This gives us:

```
checkDate <- function(date, dateFormat){

  d <- try( as.Date( date, format = dateFormat))

  if( class( d ) == "try-error" || any(is.na( d )) ){
    stop( paste0("DATETIME: Need a valid DATETIME in format ", dateFormat) )
  }

  return(d)##Added
}

df$When <- checkDate(df$When, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

df$When
#[1] "2016-09-13" "2016-09-13"
```